# Some errors I found in the manuscript after it was accepted

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have a slight issue with the manuscript that I submitted and got accepted after the review process. After reading through the proofed document, I realized that the number of studies I have counted for some of the themes we found across studies are incorrect, for example, n=8 should have been n=9. I have gone back and corrected the numbers and it doesn't really affect my results as it is just one number off for most of the errors. There is a table in the manuscript as well that has the n number of studies outlined for each theme, and the results are listed within the text as well, so you can see that there are discrepancies with the table vs the text. I know why the error has occurred but I am not sure if this affects the journals decision to reject the paper?  This is after the peer-review process as well.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the production staff the changes you want to make. If they are paying attention, they should realize that you are making substantial changes well beyond correcting typos or English issues. That means they could/should ask the editorial staff for assistance, and the editorial staff might in turn refer to the editorial board.

It's unlikely your paper is rejected as a result (since the changes don't affect your conclusions), but there is likely to be a substantial delay in the production process.